# Change position of text-input fields in Shipping and Billing

Tags: position

I am looking to change position or order of some of the fields in shipping and billing steps in one page checkout.Like,by default,we have City followed by State/Province but I want it to be like State/Province comes before City field.

Also tell me where to implement changes to validate the length/format of telephone number?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have successfully changed the positions by changing the positions of code blocks in shipping.phtml and billing.phtml of my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the order of fields in your checkout template files, billing.phtml and shipping.phtml

Magento best practice is to overwrite these files within your theme. Copy the files from base you want to edit into the exact same structure in your theme so app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Comment: can't we do it without having to change core magento files?Because check out files are in app>design>frontend>base>default>template>checkout>onepage>billing.phtml + shipping.phtml

Comment: Sorry i should of mentioned that ive updated my amswer

Comment: @Bobodevv I have tried changing core billing.phtml in my test store just to see how the new order looks but the changes are not taking place.The order/position of fields in billing.phtml stays same.my cache is disabled already.any help?

Comment: Have you tried turning on template hints just to double check what file is being displayed